# configuring maven to use a custom plugin goal

Tags: java, maven, typescript, maven-3

I am trying to install and use the maven plugin from this repo - [java2typescript](https://github.com/raphaeljolivet/java2typescript)

This plugin is expected to generate typescript definition files from annotated java classes.

I need to figure a way to run the plugin. As advised by the developer I have configured a jitpack repository and I can see the plugin dependency in my maven dependencies list but I haven't been able to run the plugin.

I added the following configuration to my pom -

in the dependencies section -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.raphaeljolivet.java2typescript</groupId>
    <artifactId>java2typescript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>v0.3.0.rc1</version>
</dependency>
```

in build section -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>java2typescript</groupId>
    <artifactId>java2typescript-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>v0.3.0.rc1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <serviceClass>com.example.rs.PeopleRestService</serviceClass>
        <moduleName>People</moduleName>
        <tsOutFolder>myTs</tsOutFolder>
        <jsOutFolder>myJs</jsOutFolder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I execute the plugin goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've picked the wrong phase. To operate on classes that have been compiled, you need to select `process-classes` as the phase. Then run `mvn process-classes` to test it out. See [the full lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html).

Also, plugins are found in `<pluginRepositories>`, not `<repositories>`, so if you had to add a custom repository for this plugin, you had to add it there. Since your plugin is not in Maven Central, I'm pretty sure that this is your problem.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>jfrog</id>
      <name>My JFrog</name>
      <url>http://wherever/i/have/put/jfrog</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: I changed the phase and got this [WARNING] The POM for java2typescript:java2typescript-maven-plugin:jar:v0.3.0.rc1 is missing, no dependency information available - although I am able to see the plugin jar in my maven dependencies

Comment: See my edit that added what I think is the other thing you need.

Comment: I am using jfrog artifactory manager and I have added the repo there. How can I configure it to come through the <pluginRepositories> instead ?

Comment: I tried out all of it .. quite frustrating.. no luck yet

Comment: CHeck your .m2/settings.xml and see how it wires up your jfrog repo.